# FormData.entries() in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, form-data, polyfills

As found on the official documentation IE11 does not support `FormData` at all or at least not much enough I need to.

Inside my code I have to loop through the entries of an `FormData` element. For this task I use the `entries()` function which is not working on IE giving me the error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'

I already added https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData via npm to my project and added it to my entry in `webpack.config.js` which then looked something like this.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ["babel-polyfill", "formdata-polyfill", "whatwg-fetch", "./Scripts/Modules/index.ts"]
    },
}
```

In the console I can see that `formdata.min.js` is loaded. As the error still occurs it seems like it does not use the polyfill as it should. It still uses the default one which fails.
How can I tell my `TypeScript` code to use the polyfill-version instead of the browser's default implementation as the package does not provied any `d.ts` files?

Is this even possible? If not - what are possible workarounds for such a scenario?

[image: Dev-Tools IE]

This is what the `FormData` object is looking like in the dev-tools:

[image: FormData-object]

which only has `append` as method defined

Comment: perhaps you need the [Object.entries polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill)?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added a `polyfill.js` with the code from the link which is included before all other javascript-code but still get the same error.

Comment: if you go to the console in the browser, is Object.entries defined?

Comment: Yes, seems like as it returns a `function(obj)`. Will update my question with a screen of the error I'm facing. I don't event know where the error is exactly coming from as I am not that familiar with IE's developer tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it may helps you but I got this issue today and it seems that the version of the polyfill provided via NPM does not completely override the FormData object, so is not suitable to IE11 or Edge.

I found switching to the V3 of the library fixed that. In order to do that I got the content of the [FormData.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/blob/master/FormData.js) file from the github repository and added it as a component in my own custom JavaScript code.

I use WebPack to, got some other issues with IE11, still investigating.

Let me know how it goes by including the content directly instead of getting it from NPM.

Comment: Thanks. I also ended up with this solution (which indeed is working). On the other hand I created an issue for them here https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/issues/34. Seems like they will update the npm-version to v3 soon, so keep tuned ;)

Comment: Yeah, happy to hear you solved your issue !

If you have any idea about mine on IE 11 here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419688/internet-explorer-11-ajax-call-not-firing

Let me know ;-) I assume we are in the same trouble about this damn IE.

Comment: Had a look at your issue but no idea how to help. In the meantime, the creators made v3.0.1 available through npm. So at least this issue should be solved then